Styling the divider of persistent footer buttons in flutter
How do I add elevation and box shadow to the divider provided by persistent footer buttons in Scaffold widget in flutter?

Please share image you want to create.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Custom Footer Divider Example')),
        body: Center(child: Text('Content goes here')),
        bottomNavigationBar: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            CustomDivider(),
            ButtonBar(
              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Button 1'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Button 2'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomDivider extends StatelessWidget {
  final double height;
  final Color color;

  CustomDivider({this.height = 4.0, this.color = Colors.black});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black26,
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 4,
            offset: Offset(0, 2), // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

